# Перемножение матриц python

Tags: python, numpy

Есть код, он работает, попытался сделать по другому, получил ошибку. Мне интересно, почему так

```
for j in range(n):
    for i in range(m):
        for l in range(k):
            #g += dataA[i][l]*dataB[l][j] ;первоначальный вариант (работает)
            g += np.dot(read_a[i][l], read_b[l][j]) ;второй вариант (работает)
            #g += np.matmul(read_a[i][l], read_b[l][j]) ;третий вариант (не работает)
        obj.write(str(g) + ' ;') 
        g = 0
    obj.write('\n')
obj.close()
```

Comment: Вы когда говорите об ошибке, добавляйте её в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[np.matmul](https://pyprog.pro/linear_algebra_functions/matmul.html):

> Аргументом не может быть число, для этого используйте a*b

`np.matmul` ведь перемножает целые матрицы, вот и используйте инструмент по назначению

```
с = np.matmul(a, b)
```

Неполноценно используется и `np.dot` - умножайте целиком строку на столбец (через срез), т.е. внутренний цикл не нужен

Comment: странно, есть оператор `@` и он делает тоже самое что и `np.dot`, но чтобы он работал нужно реализовать `__matmul__`

Comment: Спасибо, понял.